# python: write to (InteractiveConsole)

Tags: python, django

I have python script that creates django project and its apps then writes models files for apps.

This process needs to execute commands like

```
os.system('python C:\TestProj\TestApp\manage.py migrate')
```

and this works fine.

The problem that I need then to write to `"python C:\TestProj\TestApp\manage.py shell"` for manipulating some lookup data in db. I tried Popen but it seems that I missing something.

So, How could I stdout the InteractiveConsole?

My python version: 3.4.3

My django version: 1.8.0

Comment: What the message/error you are getting when you run python C:\TestProj\TestApp\manage.py shell?

Comment: No error displayed when using Popen but commands not execute. code used
p = Popen('python C:\TestProj\TestApp\manage.py shell', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p.stdin.write(bytes("from Test_pro.models import *\n", "utf-8"))
p.stdin.write(bytes("type.objects.create(id=2,name'Test2')\n", "utf-8"))
p.communicate()